# Congruency of Numbers: Last digit of $(1234)^{64} + 3,333,333,333,333$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences, decimal-expansion

What is a single digit number that is congruent to (1234)$^{64}$ + 3,333,333,333,333 (mod 10)?

Show all work.

Comment: @EthanBolker I have no clue how to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINTS: We can immediately reduce this problem to $(1234)^{64} + 3 \mod 10$ (Can you explain why?)

Then the problem is really to reduce $(1234)^{64} \mod 10$. But this is actually just $4^{64}\mod 10$. Can you see why this one happens? Can you finish from here?

Comment: I am not really sure, that concept was not explained well due to classes being affected by the hurricane.

Comment: Okay no problem! reducing $3,333,333,333,333 \mod 10$ can be done by the definition (remainder after division). Reducing $(1234)^{64}$ can be done by noting that arithmetic mod n works. I will use $[a]$ to mean $a \mod n$. Then $[a][b] = [ab]$. Thus $[a^m] = [a]^m$. Apply this to $1234\equiv 4\mod 10$ Now to do $4^{64} \mod 10$, try to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: Thank you this helps! I have not learned what the Chinese Remainder Theorem is though. @G. Snapsmith

Comment: Not quite. If you haven't discussed CRT, you can do a number of things. Because 10 is so nice, anything mod 10 is simply the last digit of the number. So, you can notice that $4^n$, $n>1$ has exactly 2 possible digits in the one's place. so you find $4^n \equiv 4\mod 10$ if $n$ is odd and $4^n\equiv 6\mod 10$ if $n$ is even. (you can prove this by induction). So the final answer to the problem will wind up being  $(1234)^{64} + 3,333,333,333,333 \equiv 9\mod 10$

Comment: @LizW You don't need the Chinese Remainder theorem. Just start computing $4^2$, $4^4$, $4^8$, ... (remember that you only need the last digit each time).

Comment: Thank you both of you for your help!  at G. Snapsmath and @EthanBolker